# Joining specific columns with conditions

Tags: mysql, database

I'm a student, I'm still learning so please bare with my ignorance.

I have 2 tables

Table 1 has Columns: W, X, Y, A, B, C

Table 2 has Columns: W, X, Y, Z

I want to duplicate data from Table 2 columns W, X, Y into Table 1 columns W, X, Y where TABLE1.A = TABLE2.Z but I can't find the proper statements to use.

I've tried select with inner join, update sets with where statement, and Insert into with select and where statements.

```
SELECT TABLE1.A, TABLE2.Z
FROM TABLE2
INNER JOIN TABLE1 ON TABLE2.Z = TABLE1.A;
```

Returns an empty set

```
UPDATE TABLE1
SET TABLE1.W = TABLE2.W
    TABLE1.X = TABLE2.X
    TABLE1.Y = TABLE2.Y
WHERE TABLE1.A = TABLE2.Z;
```

Returns unknown column TABLE2.Z

```
INSERT INTO TABLE1 (W, X, Y)
SELECT W, X, Y FROM TABLE2
WHERE TABLE1.A = TABLE2.Z;
```

Returns Unknown column TABLE1.A

Most of the time I get an unknown column error or empty result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a inner join  update

```
UPDATE TABLE1
INNER JOIN TABLE2 ON TABLE1.A = TABLE2.Z
SET TABLE1.W = TABLE2.W,
    TABLE1.X = TABLE2.X,
    TABLE1.Y = TABLE2.Y,
```